# Find a value of cell from one workbook in another

Tags: vba, find

I'm trying to search a column in one workbook for a value of a cell in another workbook.
My code:

```
If Workbooks("H:\Documents\Book2.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value 
         = Workbooks("H:\Documents\RPB1.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1") Then
UserForm1.Show
```

Every time I run it, it says `Subscription out of Range`? What am I doing wrong?

I really appreciate any help.
Thanks
David

Comment: Please, do not comment your questions for this, just edit it.

Comment: It looks like you are comparing the value of a cell with a range, you need to get each cell in the range and compare the value on it with your other cell

Comment: Thanks Juan. The problem I have is that it doesn't pull up the other workbook at all. I tried comparing one cell with another cell. Earlier in the code it opens 'rpb1' no problem but then I don't know how to make it look for the cell in the 'Book2'. Both workbooks are open at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

```
 Dim rg as Range
 Dim ws as ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
'You can change the column 
 For each rg in ws.UsedRange.Columns("D").Cells
 If ws.Range("A1").Value = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1") Then 
 UserForm1.Show
 End if
 Next rg
```

I'm trying to understand what you want.  If I get it right, you want to look in every cells in a column in a certain Worksheet if it's equal to a value in another range. 
This is just a way of doing it.

Comment: So maybe I'll start again. There are 43 files with account numbers and aditional workbook only to be used for the search. I have managed to make the search file to determine which workbook to open depending on the account number entered into (let's call it book0). After the right workbook is found and opened I need it to go back to the book0 and check the value in a1 against the cells in the other workbook. It seems that it doesn't go back and forward between the books or I can't make it pick the right book to take the value from. Makes more sense?